# Run python script with args using windows scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I wrote a script which take one switch and args
like:

```
python testScript.py --runMode 4
```

It works when run on cmd.
I have tried this same script using the windows scheduler but no luck .Is it possible to run the script which take args using the windows scheduler without using the .bat file.I tried using the using .bat file but i dont want to run using bat file.
How do i achive this script running using scheduler.Any suggestions.

Thanks